# Menu switch java

Tags: java

Necesito que este programa vuelva a ejecutar el menú principal, la opción 1 para escoger la primera opción del `switch`, luego escojo la opción 6 para salir de ese case y me permita volver a escoger una opción del `switch`, pero cuando oprimo otra opción no ejecuta de nuevo el `switch`, este es el código. gracias

```
package exito;

import com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard;
import java.util.Scanner;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.TokenType;


public class EXITO {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

       int op1=0;
        int op2=0;
        double precio=0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la tienda virtual supermercados Exito");
        System.out.println("seleccione una categoria de su interes.");



        do {

        System.out.println("1 - Lacteos");
        System.out.println("2 - Granos");
        System.out.println("3 - Verduras");
        System.out.println("4 - Frutas");
        System.out.println("5 - Jugueteria");
        System.out.println("6 - Ferreteria");
        System.out.println("7 - Fin de la compra y total");

        op1=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());


        switch (op1){
            case 1:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Lacteos");
                    System.out.println("1 - leche :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- yogurt :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - alpinito :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - queso :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - bon yurt :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    } 
                }



                    //break;

            case 2:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Granos");
                    System.out.println("1 - frijol :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- lenteja :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - soja :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - garbanzo :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - arbeja :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }



                    //break;

            case 3:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("verduras");
                    System.out.println("1 - espinaca :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- coliflor :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - zanahoria :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - tomate :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - cebolla :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }



                    //break;


            case 4:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("frutas");
                    System.out.println("1 - manzana :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- pera :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - banano :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - uvas :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - durazno :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }



                    //break;


             case 5:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Jugueteria");
                    System.out.println("1 - uno :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- monopolio :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - ajedrez :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - balon :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - plastilina :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }



                    //break;
            case 6:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Ferreteria");
                    System.out.println("1 - pala :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- martillo :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - destornillador :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - taladro :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - alicate9 :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }



                    //break;        

            /*default:
                System.out.println("total: "+precio);*/

        }

        System.out.println("total: "+precio);


        } while (op1!=7);               


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar los `break`, de lo contario se ejecutarán todos los cases.

Además puedes utilizar `nextInt();` para leer el número ingresado por el usuario.

El código debería quedar así:

```
package exito;

import com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard; import java.util.Scanner; import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.TokenType;

public class EXITO 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

        int op1=0;
        int op2=0;
        double precio=0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la tienda virtual supermercados Exito");
        System.out.println("seleccione una categoria de su interes.");

        do {
            System.out.println("1 - Lacteos");
            System.out.println("2 - Granos");
            System.out.println("3 - Verduras");
            System.out.println("4 - Frutas");
            System.out.println("5 - Jugueteria");
            System.out.println("6 - Ferreteria");
            System.out.println("7 - Fin de la compra y total");

            op1=teclado.nextInt();
            op2 = 0;

            switch (op1){
                case 1:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("Lacteos");
                        System.out.println("1 - leche :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - yogurt :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - alpinito :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - queso :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - bon yurt :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        } 
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("Granos");
                        System.out.println("1 - frijol :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - lenteja :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - soja :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - garbanzo :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - arbeja :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case 3:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("verduras");
                        System.out.println("1 - espinaca :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - coliflor :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - zanahoria :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - tomate :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - cebolla :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        }

                    }
                    break;


                case 4:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("frutas");
                        System.out.println("1 - manzana :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - pera :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - banano :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - uvas :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - durazno :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        }

                    }
                    break;


                 case 5:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("Jugueteria");
                        System.out.println("1 - uno :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - monopolio :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - ajedrez :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - balon :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - plastilina :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case 6:

                    while (op2<=5) {
                        System.out.println("Ferreteria");
                        System.out.println("1 - pala :$100");
                        System.out.println("2 - martillo :$200");
                        System.out.println("3 - destornillador :$300");
                        System.out.println("4 - taladro :$400");
                        System.out.println("5 - alicate9 :$500");
                        System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                        op2=teclado.nextInt();
                        if (op2==1) {
                            precio=precio+100;
                        }
                        else 
                            if (op2==2) {
                            precio=precio+200;
                        }
                            else 
                                if (op2==3) {
                            precio=precio+300;
                        }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==4) {
                            precio=precio+400;
                        }
                                    else 
                                        if (op2==5) {
                            precio=precio+500;
                        }

                    }
                    break;       

                /*default:
                    System.out.println("total: "+precio);*/

            }

            System.out.println("total: "+precio);

        } while (op1!=7);               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es imprescindible que despues de cada case se ejecute la instrucción `break;`, esto para que rompa la ejecución del `switch`, de otra forma se ejecutara el siguiente case.

```
switch (op1){
        case 1:

           break;
        case 2:

           break;
        case 3:

           break;
        case 4:

           break;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        default:

           break;
}
```

Para que realice correctamente las operaciones, simplemente reinicia el valor de `op2` a 0, dentro del do, el problema es que se esta manteniendo el mismo valor de `op2`.

```
op1=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
 op2 = 0; //Agregar el reinicio de op2.
```

---

Este sería el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

       int op1=0;
        int op2=0;
        double precio=0;

        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la tienda virtual supermercados Exito");
        System.out.println("seleccione una categoria de su interes.");



        do {

        System.out.println("1 - Lacteos");
        System.out.println("2 - Granos");
        System.out.println("3 - Verduras");
        System.out.println("4 - Frutas");
        System.out.println("5 - Jugueteria");
        System.out.println("6 - Ferreteria");
        System.out.println("7 - Fin de la compra y total");

        op1=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
        op2 = 0; //Reinicia el valor de op2!.

        switch (op1){
            case 1:
                    while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Lacteos");
                    System.out.println("1 - leche :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- yogurt :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - alpinito :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - queso :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - bon yurt :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    } 
                }
                   break;    
            case 2:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Granos");
                    System.out.println("1 - frijol :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- lenteja :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - soja :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - garbanzo :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - arbeja :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }
               break;

            case 3:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("verduras");
                    System.out.println("1 - espinaca :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- coliflor :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - zanahoria :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - tomate :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - cebolla :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }
                break;

            case 4:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("frutas");
                    System.out.println("1 - manzana :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- pera :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - banano :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - uvas :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - durazno :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }
                break;    

             case 5:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Jugueteria");
                    System.out.println("1 - uno :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- monopolio :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - ajedrez :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - balon :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - plastilina :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }

                break;
            case 6:

                while (op2<=5) {
                    System.out.println("Ferreteria");
                    System.out.println("1 - pala :$100");
                    System.out.println("2- martillo :$200");
                    System.out.println("3 - destornillador :$300");
                    System.out.println("4 - taladro :$400");
                    System.out.println("5 - alicate9 :$500");
                    System.out.println("6 - volver atras");

                    op2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
                    if (op2==1) {
                        precio=precio+100;
                    }
                    else 
                        if (op2==2) {
                        precio=precio+200;
                    }
                        else 
                            if (op2==3) {
                        precio=precio+300;
                    }
                            else 
                                if (op2==4) {
                        precio=precio+400;
                    }
                                else 
                                    if (op2==5) {
                        precio=precio+500;
                    }

                }

                break;          
            default:
                System.out.println("suma actual: "+precio);

        }

        System.out.println("Total final: "+precio);    

        } while (op1!=7);               

}
```

Comment: ya lo intente pero no me resulta, por eso tengo los break en comentarios, gracias

Comment: @omarvasquez Listo, reinicia el valor de op2, te recomiendo realices debugging para que encuentres rápidamente que esta sucediendo en tu programa, en realidad lo tenias "correcto" falto un pequeño esfuerzo.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo completo de un menú que hice, después de hacer una opción regresa al menú.
Asegúrate de usar break después de cada case y default al final del switch para tener siempre una opción por default.

Puedes ver el ejemplo completo del [menú en java usando switch](https://mariocelis.com/java/switch/)

```
package SwitchEnJava;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SwitchEnJavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Menu principal de operaciones matematicas usando SWITCH");
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        Operaciones operacion = new Operaciones();
        Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String opcion = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("Dime tu operacion: SUMA, RESTA, MULTIPLICACION, DIVISION, SALIR");
            opcion = entradaEscaner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if (!"SALIR".equals(opcion)) {

                System.out.println("Dame el valor de A:");
                a = Integer.parseInt(entradaEscaner.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Dame el valor de B:");
                b = Integer.parseInt(entradaEscaner.nextLine());
                switch (opcion) {
                    case "SUMA":
                        System.out.println("SUMA = " + operacion.suma(a, b));
                        break;
                    case "RESTA":
                        System.out.println("RESTA = " + operacion.resta(a, b));
                        break;
                    case "MULTIPLICACION":
                        System.out.println("MULTIPLICACION = " + operacion.multiplicacion(a, b));
                        break;
                    case "DIVISION":
                        System.out.println("DIVISION = " + operacion.division(a, b));
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opcion desconocida, teclee otra");
                        break;
                }
            }
        } while (!"SALIR".equals(opcion));
    }
}
```

Comment: No responde a la pregunta